# pika for rabbitMQ crashing while using flask server

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, rabbitmq, pika

So we have a single thread flask server running where we receive requests from a python app client. In this flask server we use rabbitMQ with pika library to distribute messages to other clients. 
What is happening is that in the get function the program is crashing with the error:

> pika.exceptions.ConnectionClosed: (505, 'UNEXPECTED_FRAME - expected
>   content header for class 60, got non content header frame instead')

I've searched a lot of topics about this in stack overflow and others but they all address problems with multi threading which is not the case. Flask should only serve with one thread unless it is called in app.run(threaded=yes).

The program normally crashes when multiple messages are sent in a short interval (e.g. 5 per second) and it's also important to note that messages are being received every second with a request to this function:

```
@app.route('/api/users/getMessages', methods=['POST'])  
def get_Messages():  
    data = json.loads(request.data)
    token = data['token']

    payload = jwt.decode(token, 'SECRET', algorithms=['HS256'])
    istid = payload['istid']
    print('istid: '+istid)

    messages = []

    queue = channel.queue_declare(queue=istid)
    for i in range(queue.method.message_count):
        method_frame, header_frame, body = channel.basic_get(queue=istid, no_ack=True)
        if method_frame:
            #print(method_frame, header_frame, body)
            messages.append(body)
        else:
            print('No message returned')

    res = {'messages':messages, 'error':0}
    return jsonify(res)
```

In this code it crashes normally in the line:

```
queue = channel.queue_declare(queue=istid)
```

But we also tried to change the code to use a while instead of a for where it ends when the body is None and it crashes in the line:
`method_frame, header_frame, body = channel.basic_get(queue=istid, no_ack=True)`
in that case.
Also important, the crashes are random and it can work a few times and then randomly crashes after a get request while messages are being sent. If anyone knows anything related to this we would appreciate any help.

Another note, we thought about using basic_consume with callback instead of basic_get but we didn't find a way in which this would work since we have to send the messages back and have several user making requests to this same function.

**EDIT #1:**
In the rabbitMQ docs [rabbitmq](https://pika.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/pika/channel.html?fbclid=IwAR3JkPQjyLQOHf0jdgBJFPieWjyCxNEP-Qk2eOpKCRMSu32ETRtYZqCMh7s) if you search for the function "def basic_get" you will notice there are some TODO comments and also a reference to this

> Due to implementation details, this cannot be called a second time
>   until the callback is executed.

So I suspected that this could be what was happening but even if it is I don't know how could it be solved.

Comment: Where are you creating your connection and channel objects?

Comment: Your current code isn't thread-safe. You'll need to check pika for a thread-safe example, or create a connection/channel within get_Messages.

Comment: @LukeBakken I'm creating the connection at the beginning outside the functions as well as the channel ( in other words only one time when we run the app). We tried opening and closing channels anytime that we need to get /send a message, it still crashed. We then tried to also open /close connection every time we had to get/send a message. It worked but we think it is too resource intensive and a bad workaround.

Comment: @eandersson What do you mean? We are not using threads. As far as my knowledge goes the code runs in only one thread as we are not using threading nor telling flask to run on multiple threads. Am I making any wrong assumption?

Comment: "We then tried to also open /close connection every time we had to get/send a message. It worked..." - this is proof that multiple threads are accessing your connections and channels in your current code that has an issue. If you turn on Pika's debug output I think you may see the thread ID in the log message, or you could add that information with a custom log formatter.

Comment: @LukeBakken, eandersson
Looks like you guys were right. As of flask 1.0 "threaded = True" is default instead of "thread = False".
I printed to thread id in each part and it was indeed using different threads, and surprise it worked when I explicitly ran flask with "threaded = False".
So I think I'm gonna leave threads ON and just create one lock and use it whenever I access the channel. 
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone interested in the solution, as it is in the other comments, the program was not thread safe since flask as of version 1.0 uses threaded = True as default.
The solution is either:
1) running flask with app.run(threaded = False)
2) Making the program thread safe by implementing locks whenever accessing the channel /connection with pika.